# Prevent breaks in redactor

Tags: craft3, redactor

I'm trying to configure redactor in Craft 3 to only allow a single line. Setting "enterKey" to false seems great for typing, but pasting content still makes it add breaks.

Here's my configuration:

```
{
  "removeNewLines": true,
  "markup": "div",
  "enterKey": false,
  "structure": false,
  "pastePlainText": true,
  "pasteLinks": false,
  "pasteImages": false,
  "linebreaks": false,
  "pasteKeepStyle": false,
  "pasteKeepClass": false,
  "pasteKeepAttrs": false,
  "pasteBlockTags": false,
  "pasteInlineTags": false
}
```

Sample content that I paste in:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Which becomes:

```
<div>Line 1<br>Line 2<br>Line 3</div>
```

But I want it to be just always forced to one line, no `br`'s. Seems Redactor used to have configuration for this but I can't see any alternatives. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Redactor is broken as hell, configuration is mostly ignored when pasting. You might have to just filter out newlines using a save hook (using strip_tags with a white-list of allowed tags, for example).

Comment: ...or use the `|striptags` filter in Twig when outputting. Or, use CSS (i.e. `br { display: none; }`). Or something like `|replace('<br>', ' ')` (also Twig), if the breaks need to be replaced with spaces instead of just removed. None of these answer the question, but are possibly viable workarounds.